# Deployment and Application Do Not Have Matching Security Zones

Tags: outlook-addin

I have downloaded one .EXE file and it got successfully installed on one machine. However, when I tried doing it on another machine I got error as below:

Exception Text

> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: **Deployment
>   and application do not have matching security zones.**    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Comment: Yes.... I tried and then posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the files in the application folder is corrupted. See [ClickOnce "Deployment and application do not have matching security zones"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/59297893-9842-4c2a-88d4-17075b1183ab/clickonce-deployment-and-application-do-not-have-matching-security-zones?forum=winformssetup) for more information.